# Memoir, etoc, Image in Main TOC but not in Local

Tags: graphics, memoir, etoc

I would like to be able to add images to the main toc to seperate the frontmatter, mainmatter and back matter. In the following example, I have substituted these for a `rule{...}`, but it is my intention to use a dedicated decorative image in its place.

Now here is the problem. In the following code, the rules are added not only to the main toc, but also to a local chapter toc provided by the etoc package:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\immaddtocontents[1]{{%
   \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect%
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\@writefile{toc}{#1}}%
}}
\makeatother

%Add Rule to Contents, Write Immediately, Will Replace With Image Later
\newcommand{\ruleincontents}{%
    \immaddtocontents{\nobreak\smallskip \rule{3in}{1mm}\par}
}%

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\ruleincontents{}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{Ch1, Sec1}
        \lipsum[1]
    \section{Ch1, Sec2}
        \lipsum[1]
    \section{Ch1, Sec3}
        \lipsum[1]
\chapter{Chapter 2}
    \etocsettocdepth.toc{section}
    \etocsettocstyle{\section*{Local~\contentsname}}{}
    \localtableofcontents*
    \section{Ch2, Sec1}
        \lipsum[1]
    \section{Ch2, Sec2}
        \lipsum[1]
    \section{Ch2, Sec3}
        \lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\appendix
    \ruleincontents{}
    \chapter{Appendixes}
\end{document}
```

How can I add images only to the main toc, but not to the local one. I need the images to be place exactly where I instruct them, which is why I avoided using `addtocontentsline`, rather using the immediate-write option listed above. Using addtocontentsline, I found that images were not strict in where they got listed in the TOC.

Anyway, I am sure there is a simple solution, so here I throw down the gauntlet.

Comment: have you not received my email message after you wrote me directly ? Your original message seemed to say the problem was with avoiding the images in the local TOCs, which is what my mailed answer did. My mailed answer did not focus on the `\immediate` in your code, but indeed you should drop it, as the sectioning commands do not use `\immediate` hence pictures inserted in toc file will get out of sync with sectioning commands easily. (if there is more than one section or chapter, I don't know which you use on a page). By the way, I am episodically on tex.sx, and will not likely answer it here.

Comment: I never received an email directly.

Comment: I just looked back at my original email, it was clear that I wanted the images in the main toc, but NOT in the local toc.

Comment: can you forward the mail to n.hamilton at unsw.edu.au? for some reason our system added some omni.microsoft address, which should be the same thing, but just in case.

Comment: I have sent to the au address. Anway, this time I could use your code here. I have removed completely use of `\immediate` which can only cause problems.